# Validate dynamically created input tags

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

How can I validate dynamically created inputs like `textbox`. I have a big form which can change from time to time.
To make thins simpler, I have a variable and in that variable I have stored all the `ID's/Names` of all the input elements I want to validate. Event the field which are to be validated is dynamic and can changed, so storing it in a variable was the right choice.

Something like the below code:

```
@model IEnumerable<ExampleProject.Models.DynamicInput>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dynamic";
}

<form id="myForm" action="">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.Label(item.Label)

        @Html.TextBox(item.Label) 

     }

     <button id="submit" name="submit">
     </button>

</form>
```

But now  I am not sure of how can I retrieve this from inside the `validate` function.

```
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$('#myForm').validate({

    rules: {
        FirstName: "required", //notice here I have hardcoded the name attribute, and it works fine. but my problem is how do i get all the name attributes since they are dynamic.
        agree: "required"
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: **You cannot declare rules for *dynamically* created fields from within the `.validate()` method.**  That's what the `.rules()` method was created to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put rules inside of the `.validate()` method, the field MUST already exist when `.validate()` is called.

However, if you dynamically create an `input` *after* `.validate()` is called, you can only use [the `.rules()` methods](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) to add these new rules.  (Although each data input must still have a unique `name` attribute, you don't have to select them by `name` when using the `rules()` methods.)

```
$('#myInput').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    anotherRule: true,
    messages: {
        required: "custom message",
        anotherRule:  "custom message"
    }
});
```

If you need to apply `.rules()` to many fields at once, then it must be put inside of a jQuery `.each()`...

```
$('input .myClass').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        anotherRule: true,
        messages: {
            required: "custom message",
            anotherRule:  "custom message"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: here `#myInput` is dynamic. I would need to loop through the variable `x`.

Comment: @user2281858, I'm just showing you how it needs to be done, so adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: @user2281858, For my dynamic forms, I call the `.rules()` message after I create the new input, so there's no need to store the name in an array.  It's pretty simple actually.

Comment: whether that input element needs to be validated is also dynamic, that is coming from my `Model` in MVC

Comment: although i am not sure how to use a variable as a selector in jquery

Comment: i will break the variable into an array. So i get the array of name attributes to be validated. Now sure how to use it then...

Comment: @user2281858, as long as the variable accurately represents what the selector would be, just use without quotes... `var variable = '#myId'; $(variable)...`

Comment: @user2281858, you've completely changed the question and now I have no idea what you're trying to ask.  The `rules` inside of `.validate()` must **match exactly** the actual `name` attribute... there's no way around this.  When you declare rules inside of `.validate()`, they **must exist** when `.validate()` is called... there's no way around this either.  Show the ***rendered*** HTML as in the browser source.